# Confusion when classifying PDE type

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following question:

Classify the PDE (is it parabolic, elliptical and hyperbolic) : 
$u_{xx} + u_{xy} + 5u_{yx} + u_{yy} + 2u_{yz} + u_{zz} = 0  $

My answer was ultrahyperbolic, rationale being: 
rewriting the equation where $x =x_{1}, y=x_2, z=x_3$ as: 
$u_{x_1 x_1} + u_{x_1x_2} + 5u_{x_2 x_3} + u_{x_2 x_2} + 2u_{x_2 x_3} + u_{x_3 x_3} = 0  $ which yields the matrix A = 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
5 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Theb eigenvalues are then $det(A - I\lambda) = (\lambda -5)\lambda(1-\lambda) = 0 $, two positive eigenvalues and 1 zero eigenvalue thereby I classified this as ultra-hyperbolic.

Even the classification matches the solutions, I do not understand how did they rewrote the solution as following:

PDE: 
$u_{x_1 x_1} + 3u_{x_1x_2} + 2u_{x_2 x_1} + u_{x_2 x_3} + u_{x_3 x_2} + u_{x_3 x_3} = 0  $ which yields the matrix A = 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0\\
3 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. 
with $det(A -\lambda I) = (1-\lambda^3)-10(1-\lambda) = 0$. 
I am rather confused on why and how they rewrote the coefficients in this fashion. 
If anyone could shine some light it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 5 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The matrix $A$ can be written as the sum of a symmetric matrix and an antisymmetric matrix:  $$A=P+Q$$ where

$$P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 2 & \phantom{-}0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

It is the symmetric part of $A$ (namely $P$) that matters when classifying PDEs.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying

Comment: Sure, you’re welcome.